# How can I pass a variable to a system() call in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unix, command-line, command-line-interface

Let's say I have a bunch of text in a variable, `some_var`, that could be pretty much anything.

```
some_var = "Hello, I'm a \"fancy\" variable | with a pipe, double- and single-quotes (terminated and unterminated), and more."
```

Let's also say that, in a CLI Ruby application, I want to allow the user to pipe that text into any Unix command. I've allowed them to input something like `some_var | espeak -a 200 -v en-us`, where the command to the right of the pipe is any unix CLI tool installed on their system.

Let's also say that I already took care of separating the variable choice and the pipe out of their input, so I know for 100% certainty exactly what command is after the pipe. (In this case, I want to pipe the contents of the variable to `espeak -a 200 -v en-us`.)

How would I do this? I don't think I can use the backtick method, or the `%x[]` literal. I've tried doing the following...

```
system("echo '#{some_var}' | espeak -a 200 -v en-us")
```

...but any special characters screw things up, and I can't remove the special characters. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, happy injection. You're looking for
[`IO.popen`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO.popen).

```
IO.popen('grep ba', 'r+') {|f| # don't forget 'r+'
  f.puts("foo\nbar\nbaz\n") # you can also use #write
  f.close_write
  f.read # get the data from the pipe
}
# => "bar\nbaz\n"
```

Comment: Seems to work for most commands! Thank you so much! One problem, however, is if I try to pipe something to the `less` command--it simply fails silently. Why might this be?

Comment: Well, it's kind of expected, I suppose, since `less` isn't outputting text, it's taking over the tty display. Would there be a way, in ruby, to exit the script while piping something to `less` so `less` could do its magic?

Comment: Now that's a new question :-)

Answer (score 7):

Besides `popen` you could also look at `Shellwords.escape`:

```
puts Shellwords.escape("I'm quoting many different \"''' quotes")
=> I\'m\ quoting\ many\ different\ \"\'\'\'\ quotes
```

This will take care of quoting special characters for you (bash compatible):

```
system("echo '#{Shellwords.escape(some_var)}' | ....")
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html

Comment: This worked perfectly for me when moving some files around with filenames which contain single quotes, brackets etc. ( Ruby 2.0 )

Answer (score 5):

`popen` and `Shellwords.escape` are good solutions but system already have a built in escaping with the array syntax

`system('argument', 'argument2', 'argument3')`

for example

```
2.1.2 :002 > abc = "freeky\nbreak"
# "freeky\nbreak" 

2.1.2 :003 > system("echo #{abc}")  #this is bad
freeky
# => true 

2.1.2 :004 > system("echo",abc)     # this is proper way
freeky
break
# => true
```

Comment: This is the cleanest and easiest way to solve the problem.

Comment: ...and most secure way

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found it. According to [this page](http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-2/), `Kernel#open` can actually open a process and pipe data to it, not just files!

```
some_var = "Hello, I'm a \"fancy\" variable | with a pipe, double- and single-quotes (terminated and unterminated), and more."
# some_command = "espeak -a 200 -v en-us" # also works
some_command = "cat"

cmd = "|" + some_command
open(cmd, 'w+') do | subprocess |
  subprocess.write(some_var)
  subprocess.close_write
  subprocess.read.split("\n").each do |output|
    puts "[RUBY] Output: #{output}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Example to pass varible to system call:

```
irb(main):019:0> b = "test string string string"
=> "test string string string"
irb(main):020:0> system("echo " + "#{b}" + "|" + "awk '{print $2}'")
string
=> true
```

> @Kerrick You still get plenty of syntax errors if you have unterminated quotes,
>   parentheses, etc

Maybe:

```
some_var = "'Hello, Im a \"fancy\" variable | with a pipe, double- and single-quotes (terminated and unterminated), and more.'"
    => "'Hello, Im a \"fancy\" variable | with a pipe, double- and single-quotes (terminated and unterminated), and more.'"

irb(main):020:0> system("echo " + "#{some_var}" + "|" + "awk '{print $2}'")Im
        => true
```

Comment: You still get plenty of syntax errors if you have unterminated quotes, parentheses, etc.